# Is there a workaround for $this within a closure in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

My IDE warns me that `$this` is not allowed within a closure before PHP 5.4. Is there a workaround for this without upgrading PHP from 5.3.10 ? See `fire()` method below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;


class UpdateItemImageSizes extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'namespace:updateimagesizes';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Updates image size information in the items table.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        $this->info('Starting chunk');
        Item::chunk(1000, function($items)
        {
            foreach ($items as $item)
            {
                $this->info($item->img);
            }
        }
        );

    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array(
            //array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If info method is public you can do:

```
//...
public function fire()
{
    $self = $this;
    $self->info('Starting chunk');
    Item::chunk(1000, function($items) use ($self)
    {
        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            $self->info($item->img);
        }
    }
    );

}
//...
```

If info is private you can't and you need to upgrade to php 5.4, because in PHP 5.3 the context in the closure is not the same of the object context.